# SBT not able to download the jars

Tags: sbt

I am getting this error on running SBT compile for the first time:

> [error] SERVER ERROR: Internal Server Error
>   url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/main/0.13.8/ivys/ivy.xml.sha1
>   [error] SERVER ERROR: Internal Server Error
>   url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.4/ivys/ivy.xml

Comment: This question is not really related to sbt-native-packager

Comment: Those links work for me. Do you have a proxy server enabled on your computer, or have some other networking problem? You probably need to quote your build file before anyone can help you further.